Python patched function mock called_with compares with modified data -- best way to fix?
I have a function (validate.py):
def _validate_data(data: dict[string,Any]):
    pass

It's not implemented yet so its a stub.  I want to verify that another function calls this one with an empty dict that is then later modified in that same function (derp_module.py):
from .validate import _validate_data

class Derp:
    def __init__(self, file):
        with open(file) as f:
            self.__data = json.load(f)
        _validate_data(self.__data)
        self.__data["derp"] = "herp"

I then have a pytest function that uses the pytest-mock mocker fixture (and also pyfakefs but that's not part of the issue):
def test_derp_init(fs, mocker):
    fs.create_file("derp", contents="{}")
    mock = mocker.patch("pkg.derp_module._validate_data")

    derp = pkg.derp_module.Derp("derp")
    mock.assert_called_once_with({})

Unfortunately this fails.  It would appear that the mock keeps a normal reference to its parameter and so when that value is later changed by adding a field the reference of course is "updated".  Then when I do the assert after the call it compares the expected parameter to this updated value it never received.
Error is like so:
AssertionError: expected call not found
Expected: _validate_data({})
Actual: _validate_data({"derp": "herp"})

I could use an intermediate variable within the Derp.__init__ function instead of just using self.__data directly, or something like that, but it seems to me this should be fixable from the outside through some parameter to patch or something; I don't want to add pointless copying just to be able to call a mock.  Looking in the documentation for unittest.mock.Mock/MagicMock (mocker.patch results in creating one of these) I don't see anything that would seem to do it.
Suggestions?
